# Correct usage of media viewport for image with background

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, viewport

I am not in any way a front-end dev, but I am writing a simple one-page website which contains an image. I have create few versions of this image to minimize the bits to be downloaded in small-screen devices. This image is supposed to be "expanded" horizontally, so I also created some background images which are supposed to be repeated horizontally. See below mockup:

[image: mockup]

Below the code which I wrote. Is this the correct approach? Is there any bug in my code or is this the correct way to use viewports? Although it works fine on my 320px iPhone screen, I can't get the 320px version to work on my desktop browser. Overall I am not satisfied.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="image" class="fluid-container">
  <center>
    <picture id="banner">
      <source media="(max-width: 320px)" srcset="320w.jpg">
      <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="1200w.jpg">
      <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="800w.jpg">
      <source media="(min-width: 480px)" srcset="480w.jpg">
      <img src="800w.jpg">
    </picture>
  </center> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
    #image {
      background-image: url("r320w.png");
      background-repeat: repeat;
    }
    @media (min-width: 480px) {
      #image {
        background-image: url("r480w.png");
        background-repeat: repeat;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 800px) {
      #image {
        background-image: url("r800w.png");
        background-repeat: repeat;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
      #image {
        background-image: url("r1200w.png");
        background-repeat: repeat;
      }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: exactly what are you expecting... you need to hide the repeating image or current image should be cover the page width .???

Comment: The central image stays central and it's "virtually expanded" horizontally by repeating the r*.png images. the r*.png is 1 pixel of the whole height of the central image. If there are other techniques to achieve this.. I'm all ears.

Comment: `center` is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center). Don't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this pen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqJRKM

Essentially, the solution is:

```
#image {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-h-c-1-480-10.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color:#f00;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  #image {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-h-c-1-480-5.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #image {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-h-c-1-480-6.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  #image {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-h-c-1-480-7.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat;
  }
}

#image img{
  width:80vw;
  height:auto;
  max-width:1200px;
}
```

html :

```
<html>

<div id="image" class="fluid-container">
  <center>
    <picture>
        <source media="(max-width: 600px)" srcset="image1.png">
        <source media="(min-width: 600px) and (max-width : 800px)" srcset="image2.jpg">
        <source media="(min-width: 800px) and (max-width : 1200px)" srcset="image3.png">
        <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="image4.jpg">
        <img src="original_image.jpg">
    </picture>
  </center> 
</div>
```

Note that with this example, original_image.jpg will only show on old browsers. It will always be overwritten on browsers above Chrome v38

Comment: Hello Leon, thanks a lot for the tip. For clearness sake: please, provide a full working solution with the 4 images in 4 different viewports to partecipate in the 100 points bounty. Thanks!

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: Or you can do it with a single background image, which feels more responsive to me, in the case that the user resizes the screen or changes mobile from landscape to portrait, having 4 images adds a few seconds of loading time : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGYJKr

Comment: But the repeated images need to scale accordingly to be consistent with the central image, in your codepen example there is no consistency. But thanks!!!

Comment: ? use your own images, the images I provided are just for example. Because the height is maintained, they will stay consistent with the central image

Comment: I see what you mean now. Added background-size:contain; to fix this issue

Comment: Did this fix your problem?

Comment: Still trying to decide/test which of the two answers to accept! One small thing is that in this version we assume that original_image.jpg is the smallest one, which might not be the case. Anyway, still have a couple of days :) Cheers

Comment: original_image.jpg will only be seen on old browsers which don't support html5 media queries. I would recommend making this one medium sized, ie smaller than 1200px, as that is what max-width is set to. You can also assume that older browsers are lower bandwidth / older computers, and make this image lower jpg quality to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

If your 1px images are uni-colored you can replace them with bg-color.
Code updated to use four viewports
Here is a suggestion using Bootstrap4 with Flexbox which additionally handles vertical alignment and excess padding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>center image</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="d-inline d-md-none"> <!-- Small viewports -->
        <div class="row" style="height: calc(50vh - 150px)">
          <!-- Extra row to vertical align the 'image row' -->
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex p-2 1pix" style="height: 300px; margin: 0 -15px; background-image: url('1px_sm.png'); background-repeat: repeat;">
          <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <img src="320px.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-md-inline d-lg-none"> <!-- Medium viewports -->
        <div class="row" style="height: calc(50vh - 200px)">
        <!-- Extra row to vertical align the 'image row' -->
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex p-2 1pix" style="height: 400px; margin: 0 -15px; background-image: url('1px_md.png'); background-repeat: repeat;">
          <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <img src="480px.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-lg-inline d-xl-none"> <!-- Large viewports -->
        <div class="row" style="height: calc(50vh - 250px)">
          <!-- Extra row to vertical align the 'image row' -->
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex p-2 1pix" style="height: 500px; margin: 0 -15px; background-image: url('1px_lg.png'); background-repeat: repeat;">
          <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <img src="800px.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-none d-xl-inline"> <!-- XL viewports -->
        <div class="row" style="height: calc(50vh - 300px)">
          <!-- Extra row to vertical align the 'image row' -->
        </div>
        <div class="row d-flex p-2 1pix" style="height: 600px; margin: 0 -15px; background-image: url('1px_xl.png'); background-repeat: repeat;">
          <div class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <img src="1200px.png">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which will give you this result https://github.com/jnfaerch/4images/blob/master/StackOverflow.mkv

Please note that the correct class is 'container-fluid' (not 'fluid-container') in Bootstrap4

If you use Bootstrap 4 you can 'switch' your main images based on media like this

```
<img src="150px.png" class="d-block d-md-none">
<img src="300px.png" class="d-none d-md-block">
```

See documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Comment: Thanks, but the 1px images are not of the same color, it's a gradient or an image which is consistent vertically

Comment: I have updated the code to use 1px images for background

Comment: Thanks! But how do you handle multiple images for RWD like in my code above? I might be misunderstanding but it seems you deal with only 1 image. Thanks.

Comment: Just add your code with multiple images where my img-tag is

Comment: But how to handle different background-images? All the images have different widths and heights. Thanks

Comment: The width doesn't matter in this context.
I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'all'?
Aren't the height fixed per media? In that case you just (as you already sort of did) insert the image and background based on media.
Please elaborate if I misunderstood

Comment: heigh is fixed when considering image and repeat-image for a given media. My question was specifically on how to handle different viewports so ma I suggest to update the answer to be a specific answer to the question with 4 viewports? Just so that none comes in and steals you the 100 points you earned :)